# How to construct TestFSMRef object with parameters in Java?

Tags: java, scala, akka, state-machine, scalatest

I am new to Akka framework, so still trying to figure things out. Indeed, I am writing some test using TestFSMRef class to test my finite state machine actor called 'UptimeMonitorActor'. Below is the code:

```
@Test
public void testUptimeMonitorActorInInitializingBothPendingState() {
  String systemSMCId = "systemSMC";
  String systemStateModeTopic = "sysStateMode";
  String dataStorageId = "dataStorage";
  String dataSetId = "1";

  Props props = Props.create(UptimeMonitorActor.class, systemSMCId, systemStateModeTopic, dataStorageId, dataSetId);
  TestFSMRef fsm = new TestFSMRef<UptimeMonitorState, UptimeMonitorContext, UptimeMonitorActor>(system, props, some_supervisor, "FSM", null);
  fsm.start();
  log.info(fsm.stateName().toString());
}
```

I got NullPointerException for fsm.stateName().toString() since I didn't know what I have to pass in for 'ev' which was the last param in the constructor. The type of the param is:

```
private final Predef..less.colon.less<T, FSM<S, D>> ev;
```

I think it's some kind of an evaluation. What should I create to pass in for 'ev' in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Steven, if you found an answer to your scenario, could you please post an Answer for the benefit of the community. Thanks